# Basic plugin does not show chosen file path / Submit on existing button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I'm trying to add progress bar to an existing form using blueimp jquery-file-upload based on the code on https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin. Everything seems working fine, but after selecting a file, "No file choosen" is shown as file path. If I reload the page, the previous file path is then shown.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>jQuery File Upload Example</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .bar {
                height: 18px;
                background: green;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="file" data-url="server/php/">
        <input id="comment" type="text" name="comment">
        <div id="progress">
            <div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
        </div>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/blueimp-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
        <script src="js/blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
        <script src="js/blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $('#fileupload').fileupload({
                    dataType: 'json',
                    add: function (e, data) {
                        data.context = $('<button/>').text('Upload')
                                .appendTo(document.body)
                                .click(function () {
                                    data.context = $('<p/>').text('Uploading...').replaceAll($(this));
                                    data.submit();
                                });
                    },
                    progressall: function (e, data) {
                        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                        $('#progress .bar').css('width', progress + '%');
                    }
                });
                $('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
                    var input = $('#comment');
                    data.formData = {comment: input.val()};
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

a) How can I get the proper file path shown after selecting one?

b) Currently, the code dynamically generates an upload button as described on the documentation. How can I use an existing one instead?

Answer (score 0):

Please pass following argument to your call:

replaceFileInput:false.

file_upload = elem.fileupload({
            formData:{extra:1},
            autoUpload: false,
            url: "uploader.php",
            replaceFileInput:false,
            fileInput: $("input:file"),
        });